# Under 99 category with automatic product assign with Layered naviagtion

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, layered-navigation, category-products

I have a category like **"under 99"** in which I need all the product with price 99 and below.

I want to use default list.phtml for products listing so design will be same as default.

I also want default layered navigation working as category page.

I have create custom block class and also used custom layout handle in category but no luck.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new category and assign products under 99 to go into that category as well as it's normal categories.  If you have many products I would modify your CSV file or use a php script to recreate the CSV then import it using Magmi or the Magento backend.  I'm sure this is just one way of many.

Comment: in question I mentioned product should assign automatic base d on attribute

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your requirement you can achieve it by doing following things:

- Assign all the products to "under 99" category.
- You need to rewrite the **Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer** model in that you need to change **prepareProductCollection()** function which initialize product collection of category.
- Add the price filter for less then 99 by using category id condition.

If you don't want to add static condition of category id you can extend the **Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer** class for **under 99** category and change above function in that.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you @Hardik, Could you please add some code! Also is it required to add all product this category ?